# Back to previous form with the same data in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i was learning to create a window application by using c#. Current i faces a problem that, when i retun from form 2 to form 1, my data get from database is gone. How can i go back to previous page without the losing of my data on form 1

```cs
private void AdminMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    string getInfo = "SELECT FullName FROM staff WHERE StaffID = '" + Username + "'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getInfo, conn);
    MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (mdr.Read())
    {
        userName.Text = mdr["FullName"].ToString();
    }

}
```

This is my form 1 which will display the username. However, when I am using the code below to return to the form 1, the data in form 1 is gone.

```cs
private void backBtn_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    AdminMain am = new AdminMain();
    am.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide();
}
```

How can I keep the data in the form 1 when I return to it.

UPDATE:
how my code open form2 in form1 is

```
private void profileBtn_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProfileAdmin pf = new MyProfileAdmin();
        pf.getInformation(Username.ToString());
        this.Hide();
        pf.ShowDialog();
    }
```

and this is my code on form2 to "try back to form1"

```
private void backBtn_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't go back, it opens a brand new form. Given the leaky ADO.NET code, this will result in yet another open connection to the database.

Comment: Please show the code how you open form2

Comment: ya, can i know how should i do to make it back to previous form without losing the data on previous form ?

Comment: What previous form? If the form still exists, just display it or unhide it. If not - don't close it when displaying another form. If the second form is displayed over the first, close the second form. And don't use global connection objects either. Connections should be short lived, which is why they're always declared in `using` blocks.

Comment: bcs im using "MyProfileAdmin pf = new MyProfileAdmin(); this.Hide(); pf.ShowDialog;" in my form 1 to open the second form. so i not really know how to display back the form 1.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but... What happens when the Staff is called `O'Donell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open Form2 with `ShowDialog`, Form1 still remains open and will continue as soon as Form2 is closed.

So, use this code to close Form2.

```
private void backBtn_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close(); // Close, not just hide
}
```

In order to hide Form1 while Form2 is shown:

```
private void profileBtn_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    MyProfileAdmin pf = new MyProfileAdmin();
    pf.getInformation(Username.ToString());

    this.Hide(); 
    try
    {
        pf.ShowDialog();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

We use try/finally to make sure the first form is shown when there is an exception while showing the other form.

Comment: Thx, it work when the form1 is not hidden. but what i want is trying to hide the form1 after form2 is open and get back to form1 when clicking back on form 2.

Comment: @AxenWong Please consider fixing your SQL Injection bug